# Creating an ios paint application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a simple paint app.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    NSLog(@"Test");

    CGFloat ok = 40;
    self.sheet.test = ok;

    [self.sheet addPoint: location];
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

This function draws lines but when I lift up my finger and replace it there is a "straight line" from the last point to the next one. How can I skip this?

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? We have no clue what this `self.sheet` is? I would be helpful to provide details of what you have done so far. Help us to help you, thanks!

Comment: replace it there is a "straight line" from the last point  ? What does that mean . Your question is not clear to me here Could you please post more on this

Comment: sheet is a custom class I have..  here is the source to the addpoint function 


- (void)addPoint:(CGPoint)point {
  self.isDrawn = YES;
 NSLog(@"add Point");
  if (!currentStroke) {
    [self moveToPoint:point];
  }
  
   
  
  [currentStroke.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
  
  
  currentPath = [self createPath];
  
  [self scaleToFit];
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

Comment: Jon Snow: Imagine just drawing on an iPod by moving your fingers around the screen. Next, imagine lifting your finger then putting it back on at  different location. Instead of the app creating a new pixel on its own at the new point, there is a line between the last touched part of the drawing and the most recent one.

Comment: you should refer [Raywenderlich's Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit)

Comment: You can reset your array of points  in  self.sheet where you are storing all the points when your touch ended

Comment: if i do this... [currentStroke.points removeAllObjects]; upon UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded I don't have any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try controlling it using UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

```
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

  //Drawing Ends.
  isDrawn = NO;
}
```

with your comments, I understood that you are controlling your line drawing method with a variable isDrawn.

```
 if(recognier.state == UIGestureStateBegan){
 [self moveToPoint:point]; // declare the point variable in the header file.
 isDrawn = YES;
 //Drawing Starts
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "end your drawing method" ??

Comment: The drawing methods are starting on "Began" state and finishing at "Ended" state.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code snippet helps

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PenType){
    kPenTypeGreen,
    kPenTypeCyan,
    kPenTypeRed,
    kPenTypePurple,
    kPenTypeErase
};

@interface MCStylus() {
    PenType penType;
    CGPoint lastPoint;
    CGPoint secondLastPoint;
    NSInteger currentStylistPageIndex;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfStylistImages;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *handwritingView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *drawImage;


- (void)initializeUI {

    arrayOfStylistImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayOfStylistImages addObject:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

    self.drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.handwritingView.frame.size.width, self.handwritingView.frame.size.height)];
    self.drawImage.userInteractionEnabled  = true;

    self.handwritingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.handwritingView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.handwritingView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:230.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    self.handwritingView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.handwritingView.clipsToBounds = true;
    [self.handwritingView addSubview:self.drawImage];
}



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    int count = [allTouches count];
    if(count==1){
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.handwritingView];
        secondLastPoint = lastPoint;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    int count = [allTouches count];
    if(count==1){
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.handwritingView];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.handwritingView.frame.size);
        if(self.drawImage.image!=NULL)
            [self.drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.handwritingView.frame.size.width, self.handwritingView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
        switch (penType) {
            case kPenTypeGreen:
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;
            case kPenTypeCyan:
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                break;
            case kPenTypeRed:
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;
            case kPenTypePurple:
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0);
                break;
            case kPenTypeErase:
                CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 6.0 * (self.handwritingView.frame.size.height/350));
                CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeClear);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        CGPoint mid1 = CGPointMake((lastPoint.x+secondLastPoint.x)/2, (lastPoint.y + secondLastPoint.y)/2);
        CGPoint mid2 = CGPointMake((lastPoint.x+currentPoint.x)/2, (lastPoint.y+currentPoint.y)/2);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), mid1.x, mid1.y);
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y,mid2.x,mid2.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        secondLastPoint = lastPoint;
        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if(self.drawImage.image!=NULL)
        [arrayOfStylistImages replaceObjectAtIndex:currentStylistPageIndex withObject:self.drawImage.image];
}
```